# java.lang.NullPointerException at org.apache.jsp.foo_jsp._jspInit(foo_jsp.java:22)

Tags: jsp, tomcat, nullpointerexception

I have spring mvc application with dummy jsp page (named htmlcontent.jsp). The jsp contains just a string:

```
HalloText
```

and this is the entire content of the jsp. The controller looks as follow:

```
package springapp.web;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class HtmlContentController {

    @RequestMapping("/htmlcontent.htm")
    public String view() {
        return "htmlcontent";
    }
}
```

The bean is added in my springapp-web.xml

```
<bean id="htmlcontent" class="springapp.web.HtmlContentController">
```

And the servlet mapping in my web.xml is defined as follow:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springapp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

When i call following:

```
http://localhost:8080/spring-mvc-hsqldb/htmlcontent.htm
```

then i get an NullPointerException:

```
HTTP Status 500 -

type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:536)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:368)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:250)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1047)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:817)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)

root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.apache.jsp.htmlcontent_jsp._jspInit(htmlcontent_jsp.java:22)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.init(HttpJspBase.java:52)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:164)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:338)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:250)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1047)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:817)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)

note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/6.0.30 logs.
```

In catalina.out there isn't any stack trace for this error. When i try to change the URL to `http://localhost:8080/spring-mvc-hsqldb/htmlcondsasdadastent.htm`, then i get:

```
WARNUNG: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/spring-mvc-hsqldb/htmlcondsasdadastent.htm] in DispatcherServlet with name 'springapp'
```

So i think, that must be the right log file. Can someone give me a hint, what i'm doing wrong? And why is the null pointer stack trace not in the log file?

Comment: which version of tomcat is this?

Comment: If you mark the controller with @Controller then you don't need to register the bean in the springapp-web.xml. Can you post how you have configured your View Resolver? And I think the url you have to use is http://localhost:8080/htmlcontent.htm instead of the one you're using.

Comment: when i call localhost:8080/htmlcontent.htm, then i get 404 Error (The requested resource (/htmlcontent.htm) is not available.")

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.apache.jsp.htmlcontent_jsp._jspInit(htmlcontent_jsp.java:22)
```

A NPE in `_jspInit()` method indicates classpath pollution with JSP libraries of a different and older versioned servletcontainer than the one you're currently running.

To fix this, you need to ensure that you do **not** have any servletcontainer specific libraries such as `jsp-api.jar`, `servlet-api.jar`, `el-api.jar`, etc in your webapp's `/WEB-INF/lib` and for sure not in JRE's `JRE/lib` and `JRE/lib/ext`.

Servletcontainer specific libraries belong in the servletcontainer itself (in Tomcat 6, they're inside the `Tomcat/lib` folder), you should not ever touch them and not have duplicates of them or a different servletcontainer anywhere in your classpath.

Comment: strange that sts template includes this jar`s. I had to delete them from pom.xml to make it work

Comment: @BalusC , Are there any blogs illustrate how to use and import the servletcontainer specific libraries and servletcontainer independent libraries? for example, import the  javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1 jar, it's independent jar, only make it in provided socpe, but servlet-api.jar is equivalent/replacement of that in servletcontainer specific libraries?  Are there any diagram/table list the comparison?