# servlet-api 2.5 & jsp-api 2.1 coming under maven dependancies

Tags: java, jsp, maven, servlets, spring-mvc

I'm building a sprint mvc app and getting the following error when I deploy to tomcat:

```
"at org.apache.jsp.jsp.welcome_jsp._jspInit"
```

I looked at the possible solutions and it seems that the files "servlet-api" & "jsp-api" are getting polluted.

Reference : [java.lang.NullPointerException at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspInit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13892810/java-lang-nullpointerexception-at-org-apache-jsp-index-jsp-jspinit)

&&

[java.lang.NullPointerException at org.apache.jsp.foo_jsp._jspInit(foo_jsp.java:22)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886196/spring-mvc-jsp-and-nullpointerexception/4886595#4886595).

I went about finding where I'm adding these files. I have not added these files in the `lib` folder in my webapp and these files do not exist anywhere in the `jdk` folder that I'm using.

But these files do appear in the build path under `maven dependencies`. I don't know where maven is getting them from.

My Pom File :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>KT</groupId>
    <artifactId>KT</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>KT Maven Webapp</name>

<properties>
    <org.springframework.version>3.2.3.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
    <jdk.version>1.6</jdk.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jdk.tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>jdk.tools</artifactId>
        <version>${java.version}</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${JAVA_HOME}/lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
        <artifactId>solr-solrj</artifactId>
        <version>4.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
        <artifactId>solr-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.4.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
        <artifactId>tika-parsers</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <finalName>KT</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                <target>${jdk.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Stack Trace :

```
type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:527)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:359)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:263)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1208)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:992)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:939)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)

root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.apache.jsp.jsp.welcome_jsp._jspInit(welcome_jsp.java:22)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.init(HttpJspBase.java:52)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:159)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:329)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:263)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1208)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:992)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:939)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
```

Welcome_jsp.java :lines 21 to 24

```
 public void _jspInit() {
    _el_expressionfactory = _jspxFactory.getJspApplicationContext(getServletConfig().getServletContext()).getExpressionFactory();
    _jsp_annotationprocessor = (org.apache.AnnotationProcessor) getServletConfig().getServletContext().getAttribute(org.apache.AnnotationProcessor.class.getName());
  }
```

I've tried adding/deleting servelet-api and jsp-api and changing their scopes to provided but under all these cases the the files remain under maven dependancis.

I've tried deleting the repository altogether and forcing maven to update the repos.

I'm using `sts`. I've tried tweaking the project facets and that didn't help either (mainly the servlet settings)

Any help would be greatly appreciated. If you need more info please comment.

Comment: paste the full stacktrace.. the root cause would be visible in it

Comment: have you taken a look at your effective pom or dependency tree? (mvn help:effective-pom, mvn dependency:tree)

Comment: Pasted the stack trace. Taking a look the dependency tree now

Comment: This is most likely issue with jar confliction.Mostly with Tomcat. Try adding this dependency `<dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>`

Comment: I've tried that and also tried that with adding <scope> provided </>. It didn't work

Comment: @eis . I looked at the hierarchy as you said and I see that jsp 2.1 comes under one of my other dependancies (solr-core) but servlet 2.5 doesn't come anywhere. Any thoughts on how to resolve this?

Comment: @SRy I tried adding that, deleted the repo and made sts update the project from scratch. The problem persists

Comment: @ThePlatypus are they inside the generated .war file? Check that. They shouldn't be.

Comment: @SRy that advice is wrong. APIs provided by the container should be in provided scope, not compile.

Comment: @ThePlatypus... as I see closely,the issue is coming from particular line in jsp file `welcome_jsp.java:22`. what is there?

Comment: @eis... yeah that's is a `copy/paste` mistake :)

Comment: @SRy I've edited the question to include the lines.

Comment: @eis When I do a mvn install I see the files in my lib folder under web app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So did two things to resolve the issue:

1) Check the view hierarchy to see if there are conflicting version of the same jar file.

2) If there are conflicting versions, resolve the issue by upgrading/downgrading the jar files to a single version